# Can I get the Ray Gun Mark 2 if I don't have the season pass?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Do I still get the Ray Gun Mark 2 even if I don't have the season pass on black ops 2?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, I played Black ops 2 before and got it twice, and didn't buy the season pass.

Comment: It would be better if you could show some proper sources too other than just personal experience.